# Can we deploy smart contract without publicly giving bytecode?

Tags: deployment, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm learning dapp and blockchain development, every time we deploy a smart contract, the bytecode is visible to all at polyscan/etherscan.
Can we hide that? Can we deploy smart contract without giving bytecodes ?

Answer (score 3):

Your code gets executed on Ethereum Virtual Machine(EVM) and bytecode gives the instructions to EVM on how to execute the code. The bytecode is what represents the contract and it is deployed in
the Ethereum ecosystem. The bytecode is a low-level language that the EVM understands is required during deployment.

when you deploy a contract, bytecode is also sent alongside the transaction in the `data:bytecode` and once the contract is deployed, that bytecode will be public. and later on, when someone interacts with your contract, interaction will be handled by the instructions specified in the bytecode. there is no way you can hide the bytecode

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no way to hide that given the open nature of the blockchain because whenever we deploy a contract we update the state of the blockchain which is immutable.

Comment: means my all solidity codes and private variables will be visible to all ?

Comment: The only thing that is public is the bytecode but not your raw code because the EVM understands only bytecodes (They can be decompiled tho' but not readable also) The only way to access your raw code is when you expose it yourself maybe via Github or Etherscan. Private variables can be read from also that's why it is not advisable to store confidential data on the blockchain.

Comment: means no one can see my codes right?
is there any decompiler of solidity codes?

Comment: Yap, no one can see your code. Most decompilers don't compile to Solidity but mostly Python-like language. So If you want to hide your code no one will see it unless you reveal it.